Difficulty in Deriving an Estimator Using Survey Means from Individual Forecasts
I would like to clarify a doubt regarding the paper Testing the Rationality of Price Forecasts: New Evidence from Panel Data (by MICHAEL P. KEANE AND DAVID E. RUNKLE). DOI: 10.2307/2006704
The paper is about the rationality of experts' price forecasts.
In this cotext, $_tP_{i,t+k}$ is the $k$-step-ahead prediction of $P_t$ made at time $t$ by forecaster $i$, with $i=1,\ldots,N$ forecasters and $t=1,\ldots,T$.
For an individual forecaster, a test of rationality can be performed by running the regression:
$$\label{eq2}
P_{t+k}= \alpha_0 + \alpha_{1} \,\, _tP_{i,t+k} + \alpha_2 X_{i,t} + \varepsilon_{t,k}^i \tag{2}
$$
where $X_{i,t}$ is any variable in forecaster i's information set at time $t$. Unbiasedness requires that, in a regression without $X_{i,t}$ variables, the coefficients in equation (\ref{eq2})
may be restricted to $\alpha_0 = 0$ and $\alpha_1= 1$.
The Aggregation Problem
Using survey means to test the rational expectations hypothesis leads to serious specification error (bias). This bias can be illustrated by comparing the results of three separate tests of unbiasedness using equation (\ref{eq2}).

First doing a separate regression for each individual and taking the mean of the estimated coefficients:
\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
 \hat{\alpha}_{1i}:=\frac1N\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k} \,\,\, _tP_{i,t+k} }{\sum_{t=1}^T   \, _tP_{i,t+k}^2 }.\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Second using the pooled data:
\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
 \hat{\alpha}_{1p}:=\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \sum_{i=1}^N P_{t+k}\,\,\, _tP_{i,t+k} }{\sum_{t=1}^T  \sum_{i=1}^N  \, _tP_{i,t+k}^2 }.\tag{4}
\end{equation}

Third using survey means:
\begin{equation}\label{sm123}
\hat{\alpha}_{1m} = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)}{\sum_{t=1}^T\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}^2\right)}\tag{5}.
\end{equation}


I am interested in deriving $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$,  in  the Equation (\ref{sm123}).
Before that, it is useful to derive the (\ref{eq3}) equation.

OLS
For this, let’s recall a simple linear regression model:
\begin{equation}
y_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 x_t + \varepsilon_t, \quad t=1,\ldots,T.
\end{equation}
In matrix form:
$$
Y = X\alpha + \varepsilon,
$$
where $X$ is a $T \times 2$ matrix with a column of ones and a column of $x_t$ values, and $\alpha = (\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$. The OLS estimator is given by:
\begin{equation}
 \hat{\alpha} = (X'X)^{-1}X'Y.
\end{equation}
Defining the sample means of $x_t$ and $y_t$:
$$
\bar{x} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T x_t, \quad \bar{y} = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T y_t,
$$
we have the well-known OLS formulas:
\begin{equation}\label{ols123}
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T (x_t - \bar{x})(y_t - \bar{y})}{\sum_{t=1}^T (x_t - \bar{x})^2},
\quad
\hat{\alpha}_0 = \bar{y} - \hat{\alpha}_1 \bar{x}.\tag{I} 
\end{equation}

For an individual forecaster, a test of rationality can be performed by running the regression:
\begin{equation}\label{II}
 P_{t+k}=\alpha_{0}+\alpha_{1}\,\, _tP_{i,t+k}+\varepsilon_{t,k}^{i}\tag{II}
\end{equation}
If we assume:
$$
\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k} = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \, _tP_{i,t+k} = 0,
$$
we can use the formula (\ref{ols123}) to conclude that:
$$
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \, _tP_{i,t+k} \,\,P_{t+k}}{\sum_{t=1}^T   \, _tP_{i,t+k}^2}.
$$
Taking the mean, we have (\ref{eq3})

We turn to deriving the estimator $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$.
My Attempt
The authors do not explicitly define the survey means. I will assume  that the survey mean forecast at time $t$ is denoted as:
$$
_t\overline{P}_{t+k} \equiv \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\, _tP_{i,t+k}.
$$
Replacing $_tP_{i,t+k}$ in (\ref{II}) with the survey mean forecast $_t\overline{P}_{t+k}$, we have:
$$
P_{t+k} = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 \, _t\overline{P}_{t+k} + u_{t+k},
$$
So one might expect an analogous derivation. Assuming $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T \, _t\overline{P}_{t+k}=0$, and apply OLS in a standard way, I would write:
\begin{equation}\label{estimator045}
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\sum_{t=1}^T \, _t\overline{P}_{t+k} P_{t+k} }{\sum_{t=1}^T (_t\overline{P}_{t+k})^2}.\tag{III}
\end{equation}
Now, let’s attempt to expand $_t\overline{P}_{t+k}$. Since
$$
_t\overline{P}_{t+k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k},
$$
For the numerator, we have
$$
\sum_{t=1}^T (_t\overline{P}_{t+k} P_{t+k}) = \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)P_{t+k} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right).
$$
For the denominator:
$$
\sum_{t=1}^T (_t\overline{P}_{t+k})^2 = \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2 = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{t=1}^T \left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2.
$$
So the estimator (\ref{estimator045}) can be rewritten as:
$$
\hat{\alpha}_1 = \frac{\frac{1}{N}\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right) }{ \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{t=1}^T \left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2 } = N\frac{\sum_{t=1}^T P_{t+k}\left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right) }{ \sum_{t=1}^T \left(\sum_{i=1}^N {}_tP_{i,t+k}\right)^2 } .
$$
And this seems to be very different to $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$ given by equation (\ref{sm123}).
How can we proceed to arrive at the exact formula for $\hat{\alpha}_{1m}$?
Thank you in advance for any help or insight.
